# Determining $\frac{\pi^2}{4^22!}-\frac{\pi^4}{4^44!}+\frac{\pi^6}{4^66!}-\frac{\pi^8}{4^88!}+\cdots$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to determine the sum of the series

$$\frac{\pi^2}{4^22!}-\frac{\pi^4}{4^44!}+\frac{\pi^6}{4^66!}-\frac{\pi^8}{4^88!}+\cdots$$

What I am trying to do is to consider that

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$ then $$-\cos(x)+1=\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}-...$$

Up to this point the expression resembles the one I am looking for, however I have not been able to find the final result, any help? thanks!

Comment: Now take $x=\pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are adding
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n+1} \frac{(\pi/4)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
which will fit into that cosine flavor when you set $x = \pi/4$...